How do I get rid of the 60 fps limit in the ursina game engine
any game I make with ursina seems to be capped at 60fps, I have turned off vsync, and development mode
code:
from ursina import *
import pygame

if __name__ == '__main__':

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    app = Ursina(development_mode=False, vsync=False)
                                                                                
    window.windowed = True                                                                                       
    window.fullscreen = True                                                                                     
    FPS = 120                                                                                                    
    box = Entity(model='cube', collider='box', position=(5,0,10), scale=6, rotation=(80,0,0))

    while True:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        print(str(clock))
        app.step()

I am using the clock from pygame to manually step the game.
this works for limiting the fps, but only below 60.
if I try to set the fps above 60, the program runs, but only reaches 60 fps
console output:
...
<Clock(fps=59.88)>
<Clock(fps=59.88)>
<Clock(fps=59.88)>
<Clock(fps=60.24)>
<Clock(fps=60.24)>
<Clock(fps=60.24)>
<Clock(fps=60.24)>
...

I am using python 3.12
and ursina version 7.0.0

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you want, but it appears you can pass a numeric value as the vsync argument (at least to a Window) and it gets passed through to the underlying 3d library to use for frame timing. I'm not sure if it expects an FPS value, or the frame time length (which would be 1/FPS), and I also don't know if it actually sets vsync mode or not (it's different than using vsync=True, but I don't know exactly how).

If it's still locked after setting vsync to False, it's probably forced on by your GPU driver, so I'd check the settings there.

It turns out this was a problem with my gpu driver settings, NOT the ursina game engine.
I was able to turn off vsync manually
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ATI#Turn_vsync_off

Upgrade your hardware. Seems it's a bit slower.
I'm running your code and getting:
<Clock(fps=114.94)>


Setting vsync false before initializing window worked for me without changing video driver settings:
ursina.window.vsync = False
app = ursina.Ursina()

